# TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y' please

Tags: python, numpy

[TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y']
please help me ((  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxGkj.png)

Comment: Provide your code and the full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit), the `fit` function has the following syntax:

```
fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)
```

I see in your image that did provide two parameters, but make sure whatever you are feeding in as your `X` parameter has `shape (n_samples, n_features)`. Likewise, for the `y` parameter, the passed dataset needs to have `(n_samples, n_targets)`. You may also provide an optional parameter for `sample_weights`, which needs to be an array length `n_samples`.

From your image, I cannot deduce whether your data is formatted correctly. However, I feel like reshaping a single column is not a good idea under most scenarios. I would suggest, after shaping your data correctly, try explicitly telling your Linear Regression instance which data set is x and y, as follows:

```
lr.fit(X=x_data_set, y=y_data_set)
```

Good luck with your journey through machine learning!